# Saving Data And Sending To Another Class In React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a little problem with an app that I am working on. I have to make something like a note app. There for I have a button that navigates me to another screen where I can write the note and I have a save button that should send me back to the previews screen and the `scrollview` shold be updated

Here is what I've tried so far:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Main from './app/components/Main.js';
import NoteBody from './app/components/NoteBody.js';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation'


const App = StackNavigator({Home: {screen: Main}, WriteNote: {screen: NoteBody}});

export default App;
```

Main.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TextInput,
ScrollView,
TouchableOpacity,
AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

import Note from './Note';
import NoteBody from './NoteBody.js';

export default class Main extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Notes',
};

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        noteArray: [],
        noteText: '',
    };
}
    componentDidMount(){
    this.getSavedNotes(this.state.noteArray);
}
render() {
    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
        return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
                deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)}/>
    });

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
                <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                {notes}
                </ScrollView>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
                    navigate('WriteNote' ,{onNavigateBack:
 this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this)})} 
                    style={styles.addButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
                        <Text style={styles.addButtonAditionalText}>Add note</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </ScrollView>
        </View>

    );
}


deleteNote(key){
    this.state.noteArray.splice(key, 1);
    this.setState({noteArray: this.state.noteArray});
    AsyncStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(this.state.noteArray));
//     alert(this.state.noteArray);
 }

getSavedNotes = async (noteArray) =>{
  try{
    let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('arr');
    if(JSON.parse(data))
    {
      this.setState({noteArray: JSON.parse(data)});
    }
  }catch(error){
    alert(error);
  }
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
},
scrollContainer: {
    flex: 1,
},

addButton: {
    position: 'relative',
    zIndex: 11,
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    alignItems: 'flex-start',
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    width: 100,
    height: 60,
    elevation: 8
},
addButtonText: {
    color: '#000',
    fontSize: 60,
},
addButtonAditionalText: {
    color: '#000',
    fontSize: 12,
    marginLeft: 40,
    position: 'absolute',
    bottom: 20,
},
scrollViewContainer: {
    flex: 1,
    marginBottom: 70,
}
});
```

Note.js: Here we have the `scrollview` and the button that navigates you to the `NoteBody` screen.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';


export default class Note extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <View key={this.props.keyval} style={styles.note}>
            <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.date}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.noteText}>{this.props.val.note}</Text>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.props.deleteMethod} style={styles.noteDelete}>
                <Text style={styles.noteDeleteText}>Del</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
note: {
    position: 'relative',
    padding: 20,
    paddingRight: 100,
    borderBottomWidth:2,
    borderBottomColor: '#ededed'
},
noteText: {
    paddingLeft: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 10,
    borderLeftColor: '#0000FF'
},
noteDelete: {
    position: 'absolute',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9',
    padding: 10,
    top: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    right: 10
},
noteDeleteText: {
    color: 'white'
}
});
```

and finally NoteBody: Here is where you can write the body of the note and you have that save button that should also save the data in an `AsyncStorage` so I can display it even after the app is closed.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
View,
Text,
StyleSheet,
TextInput,
TouchableOpacity,
AsyncStorage,
} from 'react-native';

import Note from './Note.js';

export default class NoteBody extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Note',
};

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        noteArray: [],
        noteText: '',
    };
}
componentDidMount(){
    this.getSavedNotes(this.state.noteArray);
}

render() {
    let notes = this.state.noteArray.map((val, key)=>{
        return <Note key={key} keyval={key} val={val}
                deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(key)}/>
    });

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View style={styles.noteBody}>
                <TextInput 
                    multiline = {true}
                    numberOfLines = {1000000}
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    placeholder='Write your note here'
                    onChangeText={(noteText)=> this.setState({noteText})}
                    value={this.state.noteText}
                    placeholderTextColor='grey'
                    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'>
                </TextInput>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={ this.addNote.bind(this) } style={styles.addButton}>
                        <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>SAVE</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

addNote(){
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    if(this.state.noteText){
        var d = new Date();
        this.state.noteArray.push({
            'date':d.getFullYear()+
            "/"+(d.getMonth()+1) +
            "/"+ d.getDate(),
            'note': this.state.noteText
        });

        this.setState({ noteArray: this.state.noteArray });
        this.setState({noteText:''});
        AsyncStorage.setItem('arr', JSON.stringify(this.state.noteArray));
        this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack();
        navigate('Home');
        // alert(this.state.noteArray);
    }
}
getSavedNotes = async (noteArray) =>{
  try{
    let data = await AsyncStorage.getItem('arr');
    if(JSON.parse(data))
    {
      this.setState({noteArray: JSON.parse(data)});
    }
  }catch(error){
    alert(error);
  }
}
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
},
noteBody:{
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    zIndex: 10,
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderBottomWidth:1,
    borderTopColor: '#000',
    marginBottom: 100,
},
textInput: {
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    textAlignVertical: 'top',
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    color: '#000',
    padding: 20,
    borderTopWidth:2,
    borderTopColor: '#ededed',
},
addButton: {
    position: 'absolute',
    zIndex: 11,
    left: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 300,
    backgroundColor: '#00FF00',
    height: 60,
    elevation: 8
},
addButtonText: {
    color: '#fff',
    fontSize: 24,
},

});
```

The save button only saves the last note I wrote and it doesn't even show it on the `scrollview` immediately. I have to reopen the app to display it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of things which are wrong here:

First you only fetch the saved notes in the constructor of your Main component, which only gets called on instantiation. The recommended place to put this code is in componentDidMount(). Also I don't understand why you are are passing the noteArray state to your getSavedNotes() method.

Next, and this is an important one: your methods to add and delete notes from the array are mutating (splice and push). Since React uses shallow comparison to determine when to re-render, you need to create a new object when using setState(). So for additions you could use concat() and for deletions the omit() function of Lodash is very useful. Alternatively you could use the spread operator.

Disclaimer: I haven't yet read all of your code in detail, so there might still be some additional problems.

Edit: with FlatList

```
// render() method of Main.js
render() {

    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView style={styles.scrollViewContainer}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollContainer}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.noteArray}
                    renderItem={({item, index}) => this.renderItem(item, index)}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${index}`}
                />
            </ScrollView>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() =>
                navigate('WriteNote')} 
                style={styles.addButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.addButtonText}>+</Text>
                    <Text style={styles.addButtonAditionalText}>Add note</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </ScrollView>
    </View>
    );
}

renderItem = (item, index) => {
    return (
        <Note 
            keyval={index}
            val={item}
            deleteMethod={()=>this.deleteNote(index)}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: Should I create an object, something like this :`static noteList = {
  noteArray: [],
  noteText: '',
}`

and than use this reference in the `Main.js` constructor?

Comment: No getSavedNotes() is just fine (but you can omit the argument), you only need to call this method in componentDidMount(). And your constructor function can remain as it is (setting an empty array en text), but you can remove getSavedNotes() over there.

Comment: I got that part. But I think my problem is in `NoteBody.js`

Comment: I don't think I am sending the data correctly. What I want there to happen is to write a text and add that text to the note and the note to the noteArray in main

Comment: Okay I understand now. What you need to do is handle all updates in your Main component and pass addNote and deleteNote props to your NoteBody component.

Comment: I really am a newbie so I am not sure how must I 'handle' the updates. Can you help me with that?

Comment: Here is the deal. In `Main.js` I have a button that navigates me to `NoteBody.js`. Here I have a `TextInput` where the note is written. Than I have to save that note inside an `AsyncStorage` and inside an array that is displayed in `Main.js` inside the `ScrollView`.

Comment: I managed to do this operation in a simplify version when inside `Main.js` I had the `TextInput` and the `addButton` was doing the exact same function that the save button(that is inside `NoteBody.js`) is now.

Comment: What exactly is going wrong at this point? Is the data not being saved correctly or something else? It might also help to update your code above to reflect the current situation.

Comment: Yeah. The data WAS not been saved correctly. I forgot that the constructor inside the `NoteBody.js` was always initializing an empty array and when I was saving it inside the `AsyncStorage`, I was overriding the already saved array. That means I was only posting the last saved note. I fixed that by adding the `getSavedData()` inside the `Note.js` file. Now I just need to post the data every time I enter the `Main.js` screen.

Comment: I am already using the `componentDidMount()` function but it is not working. I will update the code. Just a second.

Comment: Ok. Now you can see the changes I made. The only thing I need is to update the `{notes}` every time I press the save button inside the `NoteBody.js`. That means I have to do that every time I navigate back to `Main.js`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171074/discussion-between-andy95-and-dentemm).

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. The function `componentDidMount()` is called every time the component is displayed. The thing is that with `StackNavigator` the `Main.js` is already displayed, only under the `NoteBody.js`. So the function is never called.

Comment: So the question remains: How do I call the `getSavedNotes()` function when I navigate back with `navigate()` or `goBack()`.

Comment: I finally made it! It took me a while but I found a question group that solved this problem. `navigation.goBack()` do not call the mount functions. So we have to create a new function that is can be called before going back.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you could add a [listener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#addlistener-subscribe-to-updates-to-navigation-lifecycle) in Main.js for 'onFocus' events. I would use the callback to query AsyncStorage and set state with the result.

Answer (score 0):

Screen A
Method to do the thing in Screen A that you want to happen when navigating back from Screen B:

```
handleOnNavigateBack = (foo) => {
```

this.setState({
    foo
  })
    }

This is the React Navigation method in Screen A to navigate to Screen B:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
 onNavigateBack: this.handleOnNavigateBack})
```

…or if your handleOnNavigateBack function is not a arrow function (which binds this) you'll need to bind this: (ht @stanica)

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
```

onNavigateBack: this.handleOnNavigateBack.bind(this)
    })

Screen B
After navigating to Screen B and ready to Navigate back to Screen A…

Call the function (passed to Screen B from Screen A) to do the thing in Screen A:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack(this.state.foo)
```

Then call the React Navigation method to go Back (to Screen A):

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

I also updated my question's code so it is the version that dose what is suppose to do.